# Check Line-Status error on Read Serial COM Port

Tags: c#, api, winapi, serial-port, interop

I'm trying to use Win32 Interop from C# to improve my serial port read performance, and utterly failing. I need a very simple example about how to use the `ReadFile` method, where I read byte per byte and detecting `EV_ERR` (in particular `CE_RXPARITY` errors), using `OVERLAPPED` access.

Comment: You've probably set the parity flags up incorrectly for the port. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685090/readfile-says-it-failed-but-the-error-code-is-error-success